# how to find out the array has the variable other than the specified string in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check the array has the value other than **0000-00-00 00:00:00**  in php

```
Array ( [0] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
[1] => 2015-07-31 12:43:02 
[2] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
[3] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 )
```

**2015-07-31 12:43:02**  time may be change to any time

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: you can also try `if ( count( array_diff($arr, array('0000-00-00 00:00:00') ) ) ) echo 'other value exists';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over the array and test each value against the bad date and if it is not bad then do whatever you want to do with it.

```
$found_good = false;
foreach ( $arr as $i => $v ) {
    if ( $v != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) {
       $found_good  = true;
       echo "array[$i] has the valid date $v\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rizier123 Woops, little fat fingers strike again

Comment: You can also break the loop as soon as you find something other than needed

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_filter`:

Here is your array:

```
$items = [
    0 => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    1 => '2015-07-31 12:43:02'
    2 => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    3 => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
];
```

Here is how you might use count with `array_filter` to solve your problem:

```
if (count(array_filter($items, function($v) { return $v != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'; }))) {
    echo 'has other items';
}
else {
    echo 'does not have other items';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array`

E.g:

```
$os = array("0000-00-00 00:00:00 ", "2015-07-31 12:43:02", "0000-00-00 00:00:00 ", "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
if (in_array("0000-00-00 00:00:00", $os)) {
    echo "Got Value";
}
else {
    echo "Got No value";
}
```

To read more about in_array [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without using `array_filter`

```
$arr = array (0 => "0000-00-00 00:00:00", 
1=> "2015-07-31 12:43:02" ,
2 => "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
3 => "0000-00-00 00:00:00");
$ccount = count($arr);
$c=0;
foreach($arr as $a=>$b)
{
    if(in_array($b, $arr))
        $c++;
}
if($ccount == $c)
    echo "something present";
else
    echo "Something not present";
```